# smartctl offline test interrupts immediately

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, smartctl

When I start offline test like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo smartctl -t offline /dev/sda
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [aarch64-linux-5.15.32-v8+] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF OFFLINE IMMEDIATE AND SELF-TEST SECTION ===
Sending command: "Execute SMART off-line routine immediately in off-line mode".
Drive command "Execute SMART off-line routine immediately in off-line mode" successful.
Testing has begun.
Please wait 39900 seconds for test to complete.
Test will complete after Thu May 12 01:20:35 2022 MSK
Use smartctl -X to abort test.
```

It’s immediately gets interrupted by host:

```
Offline data collection status:  (0x04) Offline data collection activity was suspended by an interrupting command from host. Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (  41) The self-test routine was interrupted by the host with a hard or soft reset.
```

What am I doing wrong?